# Check item is in Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails e-commerce site, I have this line:

```
@cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
```

How can I check the 'session[:cart_id]' is in 'Cart' before I call this line?

Comment: You want to know if a cart by that id exist or not? or do you want to check if there is a session[:cart_id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` method is for retrieving an object using it's primary key. If it does not exists, you'll get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

The logic behind this is that in most cases, if you have the primary key, the object should exist. You can still do something like:

```
begin
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  #work with the cart
rescue
  #do something if not found
end
```

But this should not be a common case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter:

```
class MyController
  before_filter :set_cart, on: [:my, :list, :of, :actions]

  private

  def set_cart
    begin
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      @cart = Cart.new
    end
  end
end
```

That way, `@cart` always returns a `Cart` object, and you can check persistence via `@cart.persisted?` and `@cart.new_record?`